# Não conecto no Painel (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, login, codeigniter-3

Boa noite pessoal, fiz uma script para gerenciamento de conteúdo mas quando coloco meus dados não conecta, só atualiza a página e fica no mesmo local, coloquei um comando para dar erro mas nem isso.

application\views\admin\login.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Painel Administrativo</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <a href="#"><b>Painel</b> Administrativo</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-logo -->
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <h4 class="login-box-message text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-coffee green"></i> 
                Coloque suas informações abaixo para entrar
            </h4>
            <hr>
            <?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('messages'); ?>
            <?php if(!empty($msg)): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                        <i class="icon fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button>   
                    <?php echo $msg; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $info = $this->session->flashdata('info'); ?>
            <?php if(!empty($info)): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                        <i class="icon fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button> 
                    <?php echo $info; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/auth/check_login" />
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" required autofocus>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat pull-right">Entrar</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </form>
            <br>
            <span class="text">Esqueceu a senha? <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/reset_password">Clique aqui</a></span>
        </div>
    <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

application\controllers\admin\auth.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index() 
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('username') != "") 
        {
            redirect('admin/home');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
    }

    public function login() 
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('username') != "") 
        {
            redirect('admin/home');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
    }

    public function check_login() 
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE))
        );

        $this->load->model('model_login');
        $res = $this->model_login->check_user($data);

        if ($res->num_rows() == 1) 
        {
            foreach ($res->result() as $sess) 
            {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Logged in';
                $sess_data['username']  = $sess->username;
                $sess_data['level']     = $sess->level;
                $sess_data['status']    = $sess->status;

                $this->session->sess_expiration = '1800'; //30 Minutes
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }

            if ($this->session->userdata('level') == '0') 
            {
                redirect('admin/home');
            } 
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('level') == '1') 
            {
                redirect('admin/home');
            } 
            elseif (($this->session->userdata('status') == '1') && ($this->session->userdata('level') == '2')) 
            {
                redirect('admin/home');
            } 
            elseif (($this->session->userdata('status') == '2') && ($this->session->userdata('level') == '2')) 
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'Sorry, your account is not active. Please contact the administrator.');
                redirect('admin/auth');
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'Sorry, wrong username or password');
            redirect('admin/auth');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Certifique-se de que você está passando para o método `$this-load->view( )` as variáveis que são preparadas no controller. Por exemplo, na view, você nunca tem nada na variavel `$msg` porque ela provém da variavel `$messages` do flashdata, **que nunca foi definido no controller**.

Experimente chamar o método como exemplificado abaixo e dar um `echo( )` na view. Você conseguirá enxergar a variável, sem parecer que nada muda após atribuir valor à ela.

```
$data = array();
$data['minha_variavel'] = 'Charles Darwin';
// Veja: há um $data depois da string com o nome da view
$this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
```

E na view:

```
<h1><?=$minha_variavel?></h1>
```

Isto irá exibir **Charles Darwin** em letras garrafais na página.